# C# ASP.NET MVC application ContentRootPath creates list of file on server but does not find them when converted into links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# application which uses the IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath property to generate a list of files and the corresponding file attributes.  I am able to use the property to generate the "webroot" of my application.  I then combine that root with a string to "point" to a specific sub folder within my application.  This is the code I am using:

```
var webRoot = _env.ContentRootPath;
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "wwwroot/PDFFILES");
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
List<FileModel> FilesInDirectory = new List<FileModel>();
```

And this is the model for FileModel:

```
using System;
namespace AccuRecordV3.Models
{
    public class FileModel
    {  
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FilePlan { get; set; }
        public string FileOwner { get; set; }
        public string FileExtension { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public string ReportNumber { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Once I have the 'path', I execute code to pick up specific elements of each file using this code:

```
        List<FileModel> FilesInDirectory = new List<FileModel>();
        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
        {
            FileModel localFileModel = new FileModel();
            localFileModel.FileName = path + "/" + fi.Name;
            var tempArray = fi.Name.Split(".");
            if (tempArray.Length == 5)
            {
                localFileModel.FileExtension = fi.Name.Substring(fi.Name.Length - 3);
                if (localFileModel.FileExtension == "PDF" || localFileModel.FileExtension == "TXT" || localFileModel.FileExtension == "CSV" || localFileModel.FileExtension == "ZIP")
                {
                    localFileModel.FileOwner = tempArray[1];


                    if (sponsorSessionData.UserID.ToUpper() == "JRS" || sponsorSessionData.UserID.ToUpper() == "GC2")
                    {
                        sponsorToFind = localFileModel.FileOwner;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sponsorToFind = sponsorSessionData.UserID.ToUpper();
                    }

                    if (localFileModel.FileOwner == sponsorToFind)
                    {
                        localFileModel.FilePlan = fi.Name.Substring(1, 4);
                        localFileModel.ReportNumber = tempArray[2].Substring(tempArray[2].Length - 2);
                        var reportNumberInt = cf.ConvertReportNumberToInt(localFileModel.ReportNumber);
                        localFileModel.ReportName = GetReportName(reportNumberInt);
                        localFileModel.TimeStamp = fi.LastWriteTime;
                        FilesInDirectory.Add(localFileModel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This all works fine.  Once this code executes, the data is passed to my View and displayed for the user.  I use this code in the .cshtml file:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var record in Model.AllReports)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <a href="@record.FileName" target="_blank">@record.ReportName</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @record.TimeStamp.Month/@record.TimeStamp.Day/@record.TimeStamp.Year at @record.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

and this is a snippet of what the above actually generated:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/Users/jonathansmall/Projects/AccuRecordV3/AccuRecordV3/wwwroot/PDFFILES/PVSTA.JRS.R48.TN1AC31.CSV" target="_blank">Loans Issued</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            2/10/2022 at 12:35:52 
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When I run my application and navigate to this page and hover over the link, the links url is displayed at the bottom of the browser.  This is what I see:

[image]

When I click on the first link, I get a "page can't be found".  I took a screen print of the error message along with a picture of my solution tree. And I highlighted the file name that I am trying to access via its generated hyperlink. Here's the screen shot:

[image]

Am I correct in assuming that the hyperlink being generated should contain "https://localhost:5001" even though that is what the browser thinks (as displayed when I hover over the hyperlink) or it is some other issue?

Thank you.

Comment: _https://localhost:5001_ is the root of your site, not the root of your disk

Comment: Simply you don't need all that path thing. Just _/PDFFiles/filename.csv_ and this is the root of your wwwroot

Comment: @Steve - Thanks!  As with 90% of my issues, I came to the same conclusion about 2 minutes after posing.  But, you are correct.  That is exactly what I did and it all works as expected.  Thanks again!

Comment: If these files are readable by your code but not by the static files middleware that strictly prohibits reading from random locations, one of possible workarounds would be to have a single downloading endpoint, /File/Read that would just receive an argument, like /File/Read?file=/Users/whatever/else.csv. Be aware that you should validate arguments to not to let anyone read your files freely.